# react-native-sms-retriever issue retrieving message

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native and would like to listen for incoming messages from specified numbers and go on to use them. I am using react-native-sms-retriever for that but i get undefined when i check for the message received.
Here's the code:

```
const getSms = async()=>{
   
  try {
    const registered = await SmsRetriever.startSmsRetriever();
    
    if (registered) {
      
     SmsRetriever.addSmsListener((event)=>{
       
       console.log(event.message);
    SmsRetriever.removeSmsListener();
      
      } )
    
      
    } else {
      console.log('no message received')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
 }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Or any other alternatives. I have already tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-sms-listener

Thanks in advance

Comment: which console.log prints undefined?

Comment: Add whole code in question

Comment: @MohammadSalehi console.log(event.message) i should get the message just sent

Comment: log event itself to see what's included in it. I don't see any problem here.

Comment: @MohammadSalehi i tried that as well. Got nothing back